# How do I get rid of these weird spaces?

Tags: html, css

```css
.top {
        color:#ffffff;
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
        margin:0;
    }

    #Philata {
        background-color: #0431B4;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
        display:flex;
        gap:1em;
        color:#ffffff;
        justify-content: right;
        align-items: center;
    }


    body {
        margin:0;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'trebuchet MS';

    }

    .title {
        background-color: #0431B4;
        color:#ffffff;
        margin:0px;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #595859;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin:0px;
        font-family: 'trebuchet MS';

    }

    .curved {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color:#000000;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .curved h1 {
        font-size: 6rem;
        font-family: 'trebuchet MS';


    }

    ul {
        background-color: #0431B4;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
        display:flex;
        gap:1em;
        color:#ffffff;
        justify-content: left;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    
    ul li:hover {
        background-color: #4164ff;
        transition: 0.3s ease;

    }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <ul>
        
        <h1>Philata <small><small><small><em>bringing stamp collecting into the modern era</em></small></small></small></h1>
        <div id="Philata">
        <li><a href="default.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">About</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="curved">
        <h1>Philata - Website Under Construction!</h1>
        <p>sdasdasdasdawd fffffffffffffffffewefwe fwefwefwefwef</p>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#0431b4" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L34.3,122.7C68.6,117,137,107,206,128C274.3,149,343,203,411,202.7C480,203,549,149,617,154.7C685.7,160,754,224,823,224C891.4,224,960,160,1029,122.7C1097.1,85,1166,75,1234,69.3C1302.9,64,1371,64,1406,64L1440,64L1440,320L1405.7,320C1371.4,320,1303,320,1234,320C1165.7,320,1097,320,1029,320C960,320,891,320,823,320C754.3,320,686,320,617,320C548.6,320,480,320,411,320C342.9,320,274,320,206,320C137.1,320,69,320,34,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="title" class="title">
        <p>Stamp Collecting</p>
    </div>

</main>
<footer>
    <p>Copyright © 2022 Philata</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:0@gmail.com" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">0@gmail.com</a></p>
    <p>Proudly hosted by Github Pages.</p>
  </footer>

</body>
```

[image]

Hi guys! I shared my file and an image of the site as it is now. I wanted to know how I would be able to get rid of those awkward spaces that I pointed to with red arrows in the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used stackoverflow before. I tried pasting a link to my repository but it seems that it got converted into code

Comment: A user edited your question to include the code instead of a link to the repo. I was asking for you to [edit] your question to include what things you have tried to solve your problem so far.

Comment: display:block to the SVG + margin:0 to p element

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and match your expectations.
There are 2 places where I've made change in CSS file only.

*Now because we're removing margin and padding from ALL elements on the page, you'd want to explicitly expand those that you need to have margin/padding for.*

Please take a look below:

```css
/* added this */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* ----- */

.top {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    margin: 0;
}



#Philata {
    background-color: #0431B4;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: center;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';

}

.title {
    background-color: #0431B4;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #595859;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';

}

/* updated this */
.curved {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
}

/* ----- */

.curved h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';


}

ul {
    background-color: #0431B4;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;

}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: #4164ff;
    transition: 0.3s ease;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <ul>

            <h1>Philata <small><small><small><em>bringing stamp collecting into the modern
                                era</em></small></small></small></h1>
            <div id="Philata">
                <li><a href="default.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">About</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="curved"">
            <h1>Philata - Website Under Construction!</h1>
            <p>sdasdasdasdawd fffffffffffffffffewefwe fwefwefwefwef</p>
            <svg xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" class="test">
            <path fill="#0431b4" fill-opacity="1"
                d="M0,128L34.3,122.7C68.6,117,137,107,206,128C274.3,149,343,203,411,202.7C480,203,549,149,617,154.7C685.7,160,754,224,823,224C891.4,224,960,160,1029,122.7C1097.1,85,1166,75,1234,69.3C1302.9,64,1371,64,1406,64L1440,64L1440,320L1405.7,320C1371.4,320,1303,320,1234,320C1165.7,320,1097,320,1029,320C960,320,891,320,823,320C754.3,320,686,320,617,320C548.6,320,480,320,411,320C342.9,320,274,320,206,320C137.1,320,69,320,34,320L0,320Z">
            </path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="title" class="title">
            <p>Stamp Collecting</p>
        </div>

    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright © 2022 Philata</p>
        <p><a href="mailto:0@gmail.com" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">0@gmail.com</a></p>
        <p>Proudly hosted by Github Pages.</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It was caused by the margin on the `<p>` element. But there were another 4px that wasn't accounted for so I worked around that. I replaced the margins with paddings to keep the spacing. I also used the `rem` units because that's what I could see in the dev tools.

**Update**: The 4 px (or 0.25rem) were accounted for the svg being inline instead of block as suggested in the comments.
So improved solution follows.

So I added this:

```css
main svg {
  display:block;
}
.title p {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: -1rem;
  padding-top: 0rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

And the result:

```css
.top {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
  margin: 0;
}

#Philata {
  background-color: #0431B4;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
}

.title {
  background-color: #0431B4;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #595859;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
}

.curved {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

.curved h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
}

ul {
  background-color: #0431B4;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'trebuchet MS';
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #4164ff;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

main svg {
  display:block;
}
.title p {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: -1rem;
  padding-top: 0rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>

      <h1>Philata <small><small><small><em>bringing stamp collecting into the modern era</em></small></small>
        </small>
      </h1>
      <div id="Philata">
        <li><a href="default.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">About</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="curved">
      <h1>Philata - Website Under Construction!</h1>
      <p>sdasdasdasdawd fffffffffffffffffewefwe fwefwefwefwef</p>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#0431b4" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L34.3,122.7C68.6,117,137,107,206,128C274.3,149,343,203,411,202.7C480,203,549,149,617,154.7C685.7,160,754,224,823,224C891.4,224,960,160,1029,122.7C1097.1,85,1166,75,1234,69.3C1302.9,64,1371,64,1406,64L1440,64L1440,320L1405.7,320C1371.4,320,1303,320,1234,320C1165.7,320,1097,320,1029,320C960,320,891,320,823,320C754.3,320,686,320,617,320C548.6,320,480,320,411,320C342.9,320,274,320,206,320C137.1,320,69,320,34,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="title" class="title">
      <p>Stamp Collecting</p>
    </div>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright © 2022 Philata</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:0@gmail.com" style=" color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none">0@gmail.com</a></p>
    <p>Proudly hosted by Github Pages.</p>
  </footer>

</body>
```